# Get data by date in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In the database i have data : table : `product`

```
id   name     order      created_ad
1   Iphone     3       2019-01-12 06:17:26
2   Samsung    2       2019-01-12 04:05:30
3   Xiaomi     1       2019-01-12 09:07:02
4   Master     4       2020-06-05 09:17:12
5   Macbook    3       2020-08-11 14:04:20
```

I controller `ProductController.php`

```
public function index()
{
  $product = Product::select('id', 'name', 'created_at')->where('created_at', '2019-01-12')->get()->toArray();
  dd($product);
}
```

The return result is an empty array !
Now I want to get all the data of the date `2019-01-12`, how do I do that?. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `whereDate()`. Create at is date time format, but you want to get data by date only so you need to update you code.

```
public function index()
{
  $product = Product::select('id', 'name', 'created_at')->whereDate('created_at', '2019-01-12')->get()->toArray();
  dd($product);
}
```

Comment: Good answer (and taught me about whereDate, thank you).

In essence, OP's original query would only match records where the created_at value was 2019-01-12, but since it's a TIMESTAMP field, it wouldn't match any, because it's missing the time element.

Comment: @GilesBennett No problem. I am here to help you.

Comment: @deskeay No problem.